# How to Get Hash Parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, anchor

```
console.log(_GET("appid"));
```

in fucn _GET I need check if param exist and return it if exist.

```
function _GET(paramName) {
    var hash = window.location.hash; // #appid=1&device&people=

    //this needs to be not static
    if (/appid=+\w/.test(window.location.hash)) {
        //and somehow parse it and return;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I expect to see 1 in console and if I console.log(_GET("device")) or people then null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and pass in a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object instead:

```
function _GET(paramName) {
    var pattern = paramName + "=+\w";
    return (window.location.hash.match(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'))) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function _GET(paramName) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.match(new RegExp("appid=+\w", 'gi')); // #appid=1&device&people=

    //this needs to be not static
    if (hash) { 
        //and somehow parse it and return;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if (!anchro) will works too, but how can I parse value from anchor

Answer (score 0):

```
import params from './url-hash-params.mjs';

// example.com/#city=Foo&country=Bar
const { city, country } = parms;
```

**url-hash-params.mjs**

```
export default (function() {
  const params = new Map();

  window.addEventListener('hashchange', updateParams);
  updateParams();

  function updateParams(e) {
    params.clear();
    const arry = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&').forEach(param => {
      const [key, val] = param.split('=').map(s => s.trim());
      params.set(key, val);
    });
  }

  return new Proxy(params, {
    get: (o, key) => o.get(key)
  });
})();
```